# Speed up Vuetify.JS transitions

Tags: vue.js, css-transitions, vuetify.js

Is it possible to speed up Vuetify transitions? I found [this](https://dev.vuetifyjs.com/motion/transitions) page to customize transitions somewhat but it says nothing about the time/speed of the animations. 
I'd like to reduce animation time to about 0.2s.

Does anyone have any ideas as to how?

Answer (score 2):

It looks like the animation speed is simply defined in the CSS files:

https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/blob/dev/src/stylus/components/_menus.styl

Just by taking a look at this you can see transition properties like these:

```
transition: .3s $transition.swing
```

Just override the `transition-duration` and you should be able to see the speed for the animations.

Comment: Do you have more specific details on how to do this?

Comment: The styling is in Stylus so you could pull it and recompile. Probably easier to override the specific class with => transition: .1s !important; in your main css